# Comparing two objects woth themselves and each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, properties

I am a very new programmer, and im not used to things more complex than a few if else statements or some light DOM traversing.

With the help of stackoverflow I've created a test for an RPG website im building.

14 questions test the users "concerns" as a player in a dungeons and dragons like setting, and assign points to 1 of 8 personality types.

Each of the 8 types, are the properties of two objects. PrimaryResults and secondaryResults. Each of the 8 properties have the same name. 
Defender (def) , Berserker(ber), Monk(mnk) etc (you'll see it in the code)

The point is to be able to get results like Def/Def or Ber/Def or Mnk/Def 
there are 8x8 combinations or 64 results.

then one div with the a class of results appends the actual HTML results to the screen for the user based on the final scores of the test.

My Problem:

I need a line of Code that goes through each property of BOTH objects and finds the highest value, I'm trying to put that in an IF statement that results in appending the correct results to the user.

Updated Attempt on 6/5 ---

USing Azamantes' code suggestion, I find that I still get the results of DEF/ DEF no matter what the actual values of each variable are.

I've included a screen shot of what the console.log is telling me about the values vs what the display is bringing up.

For some reason when the code cycles over

If ph =def and sh = def its coming back as true.

In the image I circled a possible issue, I dont know im not an expert.

could it having anything to do with  how it says 0 for Ber on the top and has the score for ber when clicked on ? (see picture)

or could it have anything to do with the values of the objects itself? Are the values getting lost in translation somewhere?

```
$(window).load(function() {
$(".intro").appendTo('#display_box');
var question = $(".question");
var questionPosition = -1;
var results =$(".results");





var secondaryResults = {
    def:0,
    ber:0,
    mnk:0,
    rng:0,
    cle:0,
    thf:0,
    mge:0,
    dru:0,
};

var primaryResults = {
    def:0,
    ber:0,
    mnk:0,
    rng:0,
    cle:0,
    thf:0,
    mge:0,
    dru:0,
};







let pH = 'def', sH = 'def';

Object.keys(primaryResults).map(key => {
if(primaryResults[key] > primaryResults[pH]) {
    pH = key;
}
if(secondaryResults[key] > secondaryResults[pH]) {
    sH = key;
}
});

const highestPrimary = primaryResults[pH];
const highestSecondary = secondaryResults[sH];

$("#submit").on('click', function(){

    console.log(primaryResults);
    console.log(secondaryResults);

    if (pH == 'def' && sH == 'def') {
        clearBox();
        results.eq(0).fadeIn(500).appendTo('#display_box');
    };

    if (pH == 'def' && sH == 'ber') {
        clearBox();
        results.eq(1).fadeIn(500).appendTo('#display_box');
    };

    if (pH == 'def' && sH == 'mnk') {
        clearBox();
        results.eq(2).fadeIn(500).appendTo('#display_box');
    };

        if (pH == 'def' && sH == 'rng') {
        clearBox();
        results.eq(3).fadeIn(500).appendTo('#display_box');
    };

    if (pH == 'def' && sH == 'thf') {
        clearBox();
        results.eq(4).fadeIn(500).appendTo('#display_box');
    };

    if (pH == 'def' && sH == 'cle') {
        clearBox();
        results.eq(5).fadeIn(500).appendTo('#display_box');
    };

    if (pH == 'def' && sH == 'dru') {
        clearBox();
        results.eq(6).fadeIn(500).appendTo('#display_box');
    };

    if (pH == 'def' && sH == 'mge') {
        clearBox();
        results.eq(7).fadeIn(500).appendTo('#display_box');
    };






}) 







function clearBox(){
    $("#display_box").children().fadeOut(500).appendTo('#question_holding');
};



function cycle(){

    question.eq(questionPosition).fadeIn(500).appendTo("#display_box");
    $("#display_box").animate({scrollTop:0}, 500);


}








    $('#leftarrow').on('click', function(){
    questionPosition--;
    if (questionPosition <= -1) {questionPosition = 13};
    clearBox();
    cycle();





});





$('#rightarrow').on('click', function(){
    questionPosition++;
    if (questionPosition > 13) { questionPosition = 0};
    clearBox();
    cycle();

    if($('input[name^="answer"]:checked').length > 13 ) {
        $("#submit").css('display', 'block');
    }




});

$('#submit').on('click', function() {
$('input[name^= "answer"]:checked').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "monkL"){
            secondaryResults.mnk += 1.02;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "berserkerL"){
            secondaryResults.ber += .99;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "defenderL"){
            secondaryResults.def += 1.01;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "thiefL"){
            secondaryResults.thf += 1;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "mageL"){
            secondaryResults.mge += .98;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "clericL"){
            secondaryResults.cle += 1.03;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "rangeL"){
            secondaryResults.rng += .97;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "druidL"){
            secondaryResults.dru += 1.05;

        }



        })



    });


$('#submit').on('click', function() {
$('input[name^= "answer"]:checked').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "monkM"){
            secondaryResults.mnk += 1.31;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "berserkerM"){
            secondaryResults.ber += 1.29;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "defenderM"){
            secondaryResults.def += 1.3;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "thiefM"){
            secondaryResults.thf += 1.28;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "mageM"){
            secondaryResults.mge += 1.27;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "cleric"){
            secondaryResults.cle += 1.32;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "rangeM"){
            secondaryResults.rng += 1.33;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "druidM"){
            secondaryResults.dru += 1.26;

        }



        })



    });

$('#submit').on('click', function() {
$('input[name^= "answer"]:checked').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "monkH"){
            secondaryResults.mnk += 1.5;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "berserkerH"){
            secondaryResults.ber += 1.51;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "defenderH"){
            secondaryResults.def += 1.52 ;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "thiefH"){
            secondaryResults.thf += 1.49;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "mageH"){
            secondaryResults.mge += 1.48;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "clericH"){
            secondaryResults.cle += 1.47;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "rangeH"){
            secondaryResults.rng += 1.53;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "druidH"){
            secondaryResults.dru += 1.51;

        }



        })



    });

$('#submit').on('click', function() {
$('input[name^= "answer"]:checked').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "monkPL"){
            primaryResults.mnk += .96;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "berserkerPL"){
            primaryResults.ber += .97;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "defenderPL"){
            primaryResults.def += .98;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "thiefPL"){
            primaryResults.thf += .99;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "magePL"){
            primaryResults.mge += 1;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "clericPL"){
            primaryResults.cle += 1.01;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "rangePL"){
            primaryResults.rng += 1.02;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "druidPL"){
            primaryResults.dru += 1.03;

        }



        })



    });



$('#submit').on('click', function() {
$('input[name^= "answer"]:checked').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "monkP"){
            primaryResults.mnk += 1.3;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "berserkerPM"){
            primaryResults.ber += 1.26;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "defenderPM"){
            primaryResults.def += 1.27;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "thiefPM"){
            primaryResults.thf += 1.28;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "magePM"){
            primaryResults.mge += 1.29;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "clericPM"){
            primaryResults.cle += 1.31;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "rangePM"){
            primaryResults.rng += 1.32;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "druidPM"){
            primaryResults.dru += 1.33;

        }


        })


    });

$('#submit').on('click', function() {
$('input[name^= "answer"]:checked').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "monkPH"){
            primaryResults.mnk += 1.46;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "berserkerPH"){
            primaryResults.ber += 1.47;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "defenderPH"){
            primaryResults.def += 1.48 ;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "thiefPH"){
            secondaryResults.thf += 1.49;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "magePH"){
            primaryResults.mge += 1.5;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "clericPH"){
            primaryResults.cle += 1.51;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "rangePH"){
            primaryResults.rng += 1.52;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "druidPH"){
            primaryResults.dru += 1.536172;

        }



        $("#submit").css('display','none');
        })


    });




















});
```

[Screen cap of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNLIC.png)

Comment: What do you mean by 'the highest value'? That both objects have the same value and this value is higher than all the other values? Or that One of the objects has higher value than the other one (in the same key) and at the same time higher than any other values from itself (regardless of whether the other object has the same 'highest value' in the given key)?

Comment: sorry, 

I mean I want the the property with the highest value in EACH object. 

Thus is Primary comes up Def 
and Secondary Comes up Mnk 

then the results append the proper div which in this case would be 

def/mnk

Comment: So you want the highest value from `primary` and the highest value from `secondary` and these values don't have to be from the same key in both objects? I mean it can be `secondary.def` (the highest in secondary) and for example `primary.ber` (the highest in primary)?

Comment: Didn't I help you with this code last night? How much of your application are you expecting us to write?

Comment: Too bad I don't play RPG, or I'd ask for a free account....

Comment: @Barmar i'd be happy to have you play, im not looking for people to write my code. Im looking to try and understand, the logic. Because none of the books or tutorials I have found seem to be able to answer the types of questions I have.

I am also not aware of al the options available to me, didnt even know there was a let keyword

Comment: Programming is not about getting answers from books or tutorials. It's a creative process where you think about the process and then turn it into code. Finding the highest value in something should be easy, just go through all the items, compare each one to the highest one so far, and replace it if the current value is higher. So all you need to know is how to loop through an object and how to compare variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you, this is what you need:

```
let primaryResults = {
    def: 0, ber: 5, mnk: 99999,
    rng: 0, cle: 1, thf: 1,
    mge: 0, dru: 1,
};
let secondaryResults = {
    def: 1, ber: 0, mnk: 0,
    rng: 1, cle: 33333333, thf: 0,
    mge: 1, dru: 0,
};

let pH = 'def', sH = 'def';
let highestPrimary, highestSecondary;

Object.keys(primaryResults).map(key => {
    if(primaryResults[key] > primaryResults[pH]) {
        pH = key;
    }
    if(secondaryResults[key] > secondaryResults[sH]) {
        sH = key;
    }
});

highestPrimary = primaryResults[pH];
highestSecondary = secondaryResults[sH];
```

pH - key in `primaryResults` with the highest value
sH - key in `resultsResults` with the highest value
highestPrimary - the highest value in primaryResults
highestSecondary - the highest value in secondaryResults

Comment: Thank you @Azamantes 

may I ask  why does ph = 'def' 

Im probaby misunderstanding wouldn't that set the highest value of Primary to def? and therefore the results would always come up as def?

Comment: I just set it to any random key which happens to be 'def', because we're checking value against primary[pH]. If you don't set [pH] to anything then it's going to return `undefined` which is neither higher neither lower than any number.

Comment: I've updated the code with your solution. 

I tried asking if highestprimary = def and highestSecondary = def then append the first item in the .result index 

Nothing happened, no results, no error message, 

I am 100% sure the highest value should have been def in both the primary and secondary results

Comment: `highestPrimary` and `highestSecondary` are never going to be equal `def` because they are keys, not the values. `pH` and `sH` are the keys. If you set `primaryResults.def` to some highest value and `secondaryResults.def` to some highest value then pH and sH are going to be both `def`.

Comment: what is a key exactly? is it a place holder for the highest value?

Comment: If `primaryResults.def = some highest value` then pH is going to be 'def' (because 'def' is the key....)

Comment: so ive tried basically if (pH = 'def' && sH = 'def' ){
 results.eq(0).appendTo('#display_box'))
}   

and it works,

but I get the same results if I try different answers in the test, the results always come up def/def , after I added  if pH = def and sH = ber or anything else

so what am I doing wrong? 

I apologize for my lack of understanding

Comment: I don't think we understand each other *at all*.

Comment: I tend to agree, and the fault lies with me. Im very new and I cant claim that I understand the language of code.           I actually tried piecing together my own, likely very inefficient,  piece of code that works. It does precisely the same thing as yours does. But I'm experiencing the same problem as I had with yours. Works for def/def but not for anything else. If your still interested in helping me ill edit the OP tomorrow . But id like to thank you for the time you've taken thus far

Comment: I figured. Try it now. I updated my code. If you copy it into console and then lookup pH and sH they are going to give you correct key values. I thought you would've noticed that I put `primary` and `secondary` in the first piece of code instead of `primaryResults` and `secondaryResults` and replaced them with whatever names you've chosen for your objects.

Comment: The code works, I just didn't think you wouldn't have noticed that I you need to change the objects names in my code. I tend to give example names of variables and objects to show the thought process instead of just giving a ready code to copy and paste.

In the second part of my code the key for `primaryResults` with the hghest value is `mnk` as you can see. In `secondaryResults` it's `cle`. It will work with any values, obviously.

Comment: No sir, I may be new but not quite that new! I did infact change the names from primary to primaryResults and all that. 

But just incase I double checked my code and your new version and its exactly the same.  In the original Post ive updated the version and added a screen shot of what im seeing at the bottom.

Comment: I just noticed there was `pH` instead of `sH` in the second `if`... Well. My bad. Now it surely works. Here is screenshot: http://imgur.com/gRT49Ou

Comment: I swear, if it doesn't work this time I'm gonna dig it until it does.

Comment: Im so sad right now, it still doesnt work ! Made the changes you suggested. 

http://imgur.com/cWECAxj

Comment: The code I provided 100% works, there must be an error in your code. I'm gonna have a look at it.

Comment: The entire file is up top, of course the main difference in the way your checking the code nd the way im  checking it.  

Is that I have the actual HTML form questions to answer. And your just artifically inputting the values... of course in theory it shouldnt make a difference though. 

If you like ill compress the entire file, Html, CSS and Jquery and email it to you, ill even give you the answer set im using to check the test

Comment: You know last night I got kinda frustrated with this whole thing I wrote out some very rudimentary code to perform this task, and it got me the same results as yours. 

`$.each(primaryResults,function(key){
if ('def' > 'ber' && 'mnk' && 'rng' && 'cle' && 'thf' && 'mge' && 'dru') {
primaryDefender = 1; }; ` 

Now I followed this with 

`if (primaryDefender == 1 && secondaryBerserker == 1) { 
results.eq(1).fadeIn(500).appendTo("#display_box"); 
}`


I essentially got the same def/def results every time. no matter what the log said, so maybe this is indicative of a deeper problem?

Comment: If it doesn't require any database and I can run it offline on my PC then you can send the files and I'll check it. It got me curious. Email: azamantes@protonmail.com

Comment: you absolutely can, its othing more then Html css and jscript, ill compress it and send it right over

Comment: I sent you email with corrected script. And yes you could put all the check inside 1 function, but I didn't want to mess up your code too much because you're the one that's going to read it all the time. I just removed the empty lines and moved one onclick callback to the end of file.

Comment: You rock man, I didnt get the email you sent yet but I just moved it all into 1 function and it works beautifully.

Comment: Glad I could help :)